# Calculate the volume between $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z=x^2+y^2$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

Calculate the volume between $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z=x^2+y^2$.

**Attempt**

We project on the $xy$ plane the intersection between $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z=x^2+y^2$, which is the circle $x^2+y^2=1, z=1$.

We can conclude that the region between $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z=x^2+y^2$ can be described by

$$-1\leq x\leq 1, -\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}, x^2+y^2\leq z \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

The volume is given by

$$V=\iiint_W dxdydz=\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_{x^2+y^2}^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dxdydz$$

When I try to solve this, I get a difficult expression and cannot calculate it. So I think, everything I have done is wrong.

Comment: This is a good problem to use cylindrical coordinates

Comment: In addition to @NinadMunshi 's comment, use the washer method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, this is easier in  cylindrical coordinates.

$x = r \cos\theta, y = r \sin\theta, z = z$

Paraboloid surface is $z = x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ and surface of the cone is $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = r$

i) going in the order $dr$ first,

$z \leq r \leq \sqrt z, 0 \leq z \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \left[\int_0^1 \left[\int_z^{\sqrt z} r \ dr \right] \ dz \right]\ d\theta $

ii) going in the order $dz$ first,

you can set up the integral using bounds,

$r^2 \leq z \leq r, 0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi \ $.

Both integrals are straightforward to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

I obtained $\frac{\pi}{6}$ by using `Integrate[ Integrate[ Integrate[1, {z, x^2 + y^2, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}], {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2],  Sqrt[1 - x^2]}], {x, -1, 1}]`

Answer (score 1):

The surfaces intersect at the origin and at the point such that $z=1$, so the wanted volume is the difference between the volume of a paraboloid and the volume of a cone, which equals $\frac{\pi}{3}$. The volume of the paraboloid equals (by integrating the areas of the $z$-sections)
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\pi z\,dz = \frac{\pi}{2} $$
so the outcome is $\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{6}}$.